# Is travel to Europe allowed with a new portable oxygen concentrator in hand luggage?

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage, prohibited-items

I am planning to take a new portable oxygen Inogen 3 to my father in Romania.

Can I carry it in my hand luggage on the plane?

Comment: @pnuts ooops, stepped on your edit; go back and 'edit'

Comment: @pnuts Note that the [vendor has info about this](http://www.inogen.com/resources/traveling-oxygen/traveling-by-plane/) so it falls into the LMGTFY category :-)

Comment: The vendor does not have enough information... by far! it is LMGFTY but requires more than one search.

Answer (score 4):

[FAA](https://www.faa.gov/about/initiatives/cabin_safety/portable_oxygen/) lists the approved devices and the lnogen One G3 is on the list.

The [TSA](http://blog.tsa.gov/2014/04/tsa-travel-tips-traveling-with-portable.html) is fine with them too, even if the passenger cannot disconnect (which is not the OP's case but worths mentioning).

Since I am near 100% you will need to transfer in the EU, here's what the [EASA](https://www.easa.europa.eu/faq/19173) has to say on this:

> Portable air concentrators (POC) do not contain oxygen as such; they only concentrate the oxygen in the surrounding area. Therefore they should not be confused with oxygen bottles/cylinders. Under the European regulations, POCs do not have to be approved to be carried and used on board.